# Is it possible create own mail parser on Office365 SharePoint?

Tags: office-365

It seems no "Incoming Email" function on online hosted version.
So is it possible build the parser myself?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Site Mailboxes? If you could build your own parser (not likely to work), it may be unsupported - meaning, you could get it to work but the service could block it later.